# sound of flour monster

Tags: sound-design, texture, foley

Hello everyone,

It's the first time that I ask a question. I apologize for my bad english (I'm french woman sounddesigner).
I need to create a flour monster for an animated movie. 
I used the snow foley for texture, but it misses something.
Which another texture can I use?

Thanks for your response

Answer (score 4):

Try crushing coarse sugar with your fingers in sync to the creature's movement, but layer it on top of the existing cloth and snow sounds.  The roughness will add a suggestion of the internal movement of flour within the creature.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a fun challenge!

Flour is soft, not coarse like sugar. Maybe very soft, pillowy sounds would be good to add: Impacts into pillows, cloth hits, maybe even foley of things being dropped into talcum powder or flour itself (guaranteed to be messier than any liquid, though). Maybe even experiment with snow foley?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try watching and listening to Spiderman 3, and the sandman scenes. I remember these as being very well made.
http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rXOa5bWFRKw

Answer (score 1):

granular synthesis and animal sounds :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your responses :)

Yes, it's a fun challenge.
I used cloth hits with an LPF and snow avalanche with an EQ, to have the texture. And I'm pretty happy of the result.

For the voice of the monster, I tried to use the granular synthesis, but the result is not really the way I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How about re-voicing the dialogue with a low breathy mumble underneath the existing dialogue so it sounds like an evolving wind?

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. Maybe can I play with a low mumble and reverse effect.
The idea of an evolving wind is good I think ;)

Comment: You might consider vocoding the dialog as well. Try wind, or perhaps the snow avalanche you used, as the carrier signal. Putting the voice through a unique impulse response using a convolution reverb plugin can also give you cool effects.

Answer (score 0):

I have some results with the reverse effect on the mumble.
I don't know how I can explain it, but How can I do a sound which sounds like dust, for the texture? Maybe can I do a morphing with the voice and the texture?